# python string to '\x' hex number conversion

Tags: python

sorry new to python, I have done a couple of searches but failed to get the answer I wanted.

So let's say I have a string **'3918f33a'**
but I want my final output to equal to:

**output ='\x3a\xf3\x18\x39'**

so when I **print(output)** I will get:

**:ó▒9**

how do I go about doing that?
I have tried to combine "\x"+string[6:8] .. but it will only error out.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use some appropriate slicing within a `for` loop or list comprehension; an example:

```py
a = '3918f33a'
output = ''.join(r'\x' + a[i-2:i] for i in range(len(a), 0, -2))
print(output) # \x3a\xf3\x18\x39
```

Comment: Hi lee thanks for the fast response, it is my fault that I wasn't been fully clear on the question. Yes, the output would print the \x3a\xf3\x18\x39, but I actually want the output variable to actually equal to '\x3a\xf3\x18\x39'. right now the value of the output variable is actually '\\x3a\\xf3\\x18\\x39'